# i cant compile matlab generated code, it gives me a linker error what is the correct step i have to follow?

Tags: matlab, visual-c++, matlab-deployment, mixed-programming

i was trying to learn matlab to C workflow and i used a matlab coder to generate C/C++ code from this .m file

```
  function c = simpleProduct(a,b) %#codegen
  c=a*b;
```

and after the code has been generated my visual win32 c++ project looks like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "simpleProduct.h"  //matlab generated header file.
using namespace std;
void main(){
    cout<<simpleProduct(34,55);   //matlab generated funcion
}
```

i even configured "addition library" and "additional dependency" from project properties to my generated static library but the same problem occurs again and again.

and from this code i generated a static library. and the operation is success on matlab. but when i included the generated header file and linked the static library inside visual studio and compiled it it gives me this error.

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "float __cdecl simpleProduct(float,float)" (?simpleProduct@@YAMMM@Z) referenced in function _main C:\Users\serakpc\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\chiraq\chiraq\source.obj chiraq
```

development environments----
Matlab 2012b,
Visual Studio 2012,
Visual Studio 2010,

Comment: Where's the function definition? This sounds like you either aren't linking properly or are missing the function definition code.

Comment: here is simpleproduct.c look like `real32_T simpleProduct(real32_T a, real32_T b)
{
  return a * b;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your visual studio project cannot found `simpleProduct.dll`.

Solution: When you distribute MATLAB into visual studio, it will generate (at least) four files namely

1. `simpleProduct.h`
2. `simpleProduct.lib`
3. `simpleProduct.dll`
4. `simpleProduct.ctf`

You need to copy these 4 files to your visual studio solution directory and add `simpleProduct.lib`  to [`Properties > Linker > Input`].